# Homomorphism from unit circle to unit circle

Tags: group-theory, circles, group-homomorphism

In this question [$\varphi$ in $\operatorname{Hom}{(S^1, S^1)}$ are of the form $z^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123588/varphi-in-operatornamehoms1-s1-are-of-the-form-zn) all the continuous homomorphisms from $S^1$ to $S^1$ are characterized. However I am looking for non continuous homomorphisms.

My observations are
$S^1$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Any subgroup of $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ is in the form $\frac{H}{\mathbb{Z}}$ where $H$ is a subgroup of real numbers containing integers.

If $H$ is generated by $1/n$ then we get $\frac{H}{\mathbb{Z}}$ as the kernel of continuous homomorphisms.

So it is possible to show the existence of non continuous homomorphisms if we can find a non cyclic subgroup $H$ of real numbers such that $\mathbb{R}/H$ is subgroup of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. But I am not able to find any such H explicitly.

Is there a way to improve this or any alternative ways?

Comment: For example, it is easy to see that the subgroup $H=\{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is not cyclic.

Comment: @kabenyuk Yes, it's easy to find examples of subgroups of real numbers. But is it easy to see whether their quotient is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Here's another example. There is an injective homomorphism $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. See the theory of abelian divisible groups.

Comment: @If you can provide some more details it'll be helpful or even you could write an answer.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427460/non-continuous-homomorphism-from-unit-circle-to-unit-circle without notice of crosspost to either site – an abuse of both sites.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is an uncountable-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, so (assuming the axiom of choice) it has an uncountable basis and hence can be written as an uncountable direct sum $\bigoplus_I \mathbb{Q}$. One of these copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be chosen to contain $\mathbb{Z}$. The result is that we have an abstract isomorphism

$$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \oplus \bigoplus_J \mathbb{Q}$$

where $J$ is $I$ with one element removed. There are no nonzero homomorphisms from the first summand to the second. This gives

$$\text{End}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) \cong \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \text{End}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) & \text{Hom}(\bigoplus_J \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \\ 0 & \text{End}(\bigoplus_J \mathbb{Q}) \end{array} \right].$$

All three of these can be calculated as follows. $\text{End}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ turns out to be the [profinite integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer) $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \cong \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$. $\text{End}(\bigoplus_J \mathbb{Q})$ is an uncountable-dimensional (column-finite) matrix algebra $M_J(\mathbb{Q})$. And $\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_J \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \cong \prod_J \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$. $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is a bit tricky to describe but you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2105854/232) that one possible description is $\mathbb{Q} \otimes \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, and you can find another description working one prime at a time towards the end of [these notes](https://math.jhu.edu/~jmb/note/torext.pdf).

So this is a more or less complete description of all endomorphisms, nearly all of which are highly discontinuous.